# installing elfinder web file manager

Tags: web, file-manager, elfinder

i have a share linux apach host and i put elfinder in public_html/js/elfinder and this is my connector.php setting

```
array( 
'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem', // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED) 
'path' => '/uploads', // path to files (REQUIRED) 
'URL' => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/uploads', // URL to files (REQUIRED) 
'accessControl' => 'access' // disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL) 
)
```

and this is my jquery setting

```
$().ready(function() { 
var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({ 
url : 'js/elfinder/php/connector.php' // connector URL (REQUIRED) 
}).elfinder('instance'); 
});
```

but when i go to elfinder page this error show 
Unable to connect to backend. 
Backend not found. 
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the appropriate permissions over the elfinder folders? 755 on folders and 644 on files.

Answer (score 0):

your file tree is not good

change the path to files from  `'path' => '/uploads', //` to

```
'path' => '../uploads', // path to files
```

change all  tags (link and script scr)

prefix links like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/elfinder/js/elfinder.min.js"></script>
```

your prefix is : `js/elfinder/js/` and `js/elfinder/js/css`